# What's the passive form of "A lives (or resides) in B"?

Tags: passive-voice

I could easily say "Currently, there are six people living in that manor", but how do I turn it into passive sentence so that the manor becomes the subject?

I was trying to make a sentence about a group of five people renting an apartment house together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "That manor is lived in by six people"

If you're not happy with that, use a transitive verb such as "occupy" or "inhabit".

Answer (score 3):

*I was trying to make a sentence about a group of five people renting an apartment house together.*

The manor is currently home to five people.

("The manor houses six people" could imply that only that number of people can live there, which may not be accurate if more could fit in.)

Comment: True on the possible ambiguity from using the word "house."  That could be somewhat resolved using the word _currently_, and you did: _The manor currently houses six people._

Answer (score 2):

You could also say:

> ***That manor has six people living in it.***

Answer (score 1):

This works:

> *The manor houses six people.*

*House* can be used as a verb; it means:

> **house** (transitive verb) 1 a : to provide with living quarters or shelter b : to store in a house 2 : to encase, enclose, or shelter as
>   if by putting in a house 3 : to serve as a shelter or container for

```
(definition taken from Merriam-Webster's online dictionary)
```